# Is there a way to tell if an android device is wifi-only?

Tags: android

I am trying to find a reliable way to tell if an Android device is wifi-only. I tried a couple of ways:

-- Try to get device ID (IMEI/MEID), if I can not get the IMEI/MEID number, then I can assume the device is wifi-only. This doesn't work as some phones do not return a device ID when they are put in flight mode.
-- Try to read TelephonyManager.getPhoneType. This doesn't work either as the wifi-only device I am testing with returns PHONE_TYPE_GSM, while I expect it to return PHONE_TYPE_NONE.

I wonder if anyone has successfully distinguish wifi-only devices and the non-wifi-only ones.

Answer (score 5):

You could query the system features in your app to see if that works.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean isAPhone = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
```

If you care about GSM/CDMA use the more specific `FEATURE_TELEPHONY_GSM` or `FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA`.

If the device is lying there is of course not much you can do afaik.

Comment: Unfortunately my wifi only device thinks it is a GSM phone.

I am considering to combine the value of IMEI/MEID and Airplane mode to decide --
If I can not retrieve IMEI/MEID and the Airplane mode is Off, then I consider it a wifi-only device. 
The way I retrieve the airplane mode is using 
     Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),                 
     Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

Airplane mode returns Off on my wifi-only test device. Not sure if it will behave the same on other wifi-only devices...

Comment: In my device i don't have gsm module (wifi-only device), but 'pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);' return true.

Answer (score 2):

Following solution worked for me better:

```
TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager)ctx.getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );
return mgr.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE;
```

And following did NOT work on few devices like Nook Tablet:

```
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
return pm.hasSystemFeature( PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem to yours and I checked out several solutions. Only one of them works reliably thus far

```
if (mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) == null) {
    // wifi-only device
}
```

This assumption is wrong. My wifi-only Nexus 7 returns a Telephony Manager object.

```
mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)
```

This returns false on both my Nexus 7. One of them supports data connections and the other one is wifi-only

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)
telMgr.getPhoneType()
```

I expect `PHONE_TYPE_NONE` for the nexus 7 that is wifi-only and `PHONE_TYPE_GSM` for the other Nexus 7. I get `PHONE_TYPE_NONE` for both Nexus 7

```
if(telMgr.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN) {
    // Wifi-only device
}
else if (telMgr.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) {
    // Device that supports data connection, but no SIM card present
}
```

This solution worries me. `SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN` is also used during state transitions. Also, some devices support data connections but don't have a SIM card.

My favourite solution is the following

```
ConnectivityManager mConMgr = mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
if (mConMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) == null) {
    //wifi-only device
}
```

The only thing that worries me is if there are devices which support `TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI` or `TYPE_MOBILE_MMS` but not `TYPE_MOBILE` I suspect this is not the case.